# Problema a la hora de añadir objetos de una nueva clase en Java

Tags: java

Estamos realizando un videojuego en Java de naves, y mi problema es que cuando he declarado nuevas coordenadas, el rectángulo y la ventaja me da error cuando ya hay declaradas otros elementos.

Problema lo da en la clase `Ventaja.java` y `AsteroidesMain.java.`

> Ventaja.java [error linea 5, 17, 17, 30 y 31] Linea 5: public class
>   Ventaja extends Actor {.
>        17: public Ventaja(Rectangulo rectangulo, String ficheroImagen, Escenario escenario, int velocidadVentaja){
>        30: Rectangulo r =this.getRectangulo();
>        31: Coordenada c =r.getCoordenada();

```
package src;

import java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory;

public class Ventaja extends Actor {

    private int velocidadVentaja = 0;
    int a;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase Ventaja
     * @param velocidad Velocidad a la que ira el asteroide.
     * @param rectangulo Rectangulo en el que esta contenido el asteroide.
     * @param ficheroImagen Imagen que tendra la ventaja
     * @param escenario Escenario en el que se ubicara la Ventaja.
     */
    public Ventaja(Rectangulo rectangulo, String ficheroImagen, Escenario escenario, int velocidadVentaja){
        super(rectangulo, ficheroImagen, escenario);
        if(velocidadVentaja >= 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("La velocidad es menor o igual a 0.");
        }
        this.velocidadVentaja = velocidadVentaja;
    }

    /**
     * Realiza sus acciones.
     */

    public void actuar(){
        Rectangulo r =this.getRectangulo();
        Coordenada c =r.getCoordenada();
        int aleatorio =(int)(Math.random()*460);
        if(c.getX()==0){
            r.setCoordenada(460, aleatorio);
        }
        else
            r.setCoordenada(c.getX()+velocidadVentaja, c.getY());
    }
}
```

AsteroidesMain.java

> [error linea 109(Rectangulo r7 = new Rectagulo(c6,80,110);) y
>   119(Ventaja v1 = new Ventaja(r7, "ventaja.png", m,-1);)]

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

File fichero = new File("fjugadores.txt");

Set<Jugador> jugadores = new HashSet<Jugador>();


/*
SimpleGUI sg = new SimpleGUI();
sg.drawImage("testImage.jpg",0,0,0,0,"");
sleep(5000);
sg.stop()

*/

     EscenarioAsteroides m = new EscenarioAsteroides(500,500);       // Creamos el escenario. 
     Coordenada c1 = new Coordenada(0,250);                          // Coordenadas para la nave 1
     Coordenada c2 = new Coordenada(200,350);                        // Coordenadas para el asteroide 1 
     Coordenada c3 = new Coordenada(500,100);                        // Coordenadas para el asteroide 2
     Coordenada c4 = new Coordenada(150,100);                        // Coordenadas para la nave extraterrestre
     Coordenada c5 = new Coordenada(375,147);                        // Coordenadas para Roger el extraterrestre
     Coordenada c6 = new Coordenada(175,200);                        // Coordenadas para la ventaja 1

     Rectangulo r1 = new Rectangulo(c1,60,50);                       // Rectangulo donde dibujar la nave 1
     Rectangulo r2 = new Rectangulo(c1,80,90);                       // Rectangulo donde dibujar la nave 2 (ancho, alto)
     Rectangulo r3 = new Rectangulo(c2,40,40);                       // Rectangulo para pintar los asteroides  
     Rectangulo r4 = new Rectangulo(c3,40,40);                       // Rectangulo para pintar los asteroides  
     Rectangulo r5 = new Rectangulo(c4,60,60);                       // Rectangulo para pintar una nave extraterrestre 
     Rectangulo r6 = new Rectangulo(c5,100,100);                     // Rectangulo para pintar a Roger el extraterrestre
     Rectangulo r7 = new Rectagulo(c6,80,110);                       // Rectangulo para pintar la ventaja 1

  // Creamos las naves y asteroides 

     Nave nave1 = new Nave(r1, "n1.png", m,1);
     Nave nave2 = new Nave(r2, "n2.png", m,1); 
     Asteroide a1 = new Asteroide(r3, "a3.png",m,-1);
     Asteroide a2 = new Asteroide(r4, "a3.png",m,-1);
     Asteroide a3 = new Asteroide(r5, "a4.png",m,-1); // nave extraterrestre
     Asteroide a4 = new Asteroide(r6, "a5.png",m,-1); // Roger el extraterrestre
     Ventaja v1 = new Ventaja(r7, "ventaja.png", m,-1); // Imagen Ventaja
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo debe ir escrito en la pregunta, no como fotos. ademas debes decir donde tienes exactamente el problema.

Comment: Añade texto no imágenes de código y revisa los enlaces que te proporciona gbianchi, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: ¿Por qué tanta gente adjunta capturas de pantalla, con lo engorroso que es crear las imágenes y subirlas, en lugar de copiar y pegar el código como texto? Hay que plantearse algún tipo de aviso más visible para los nuevos usuarios

Comment: Hoa, es imposible replicar tu problema con fotos del código.

Comment: Buenas, ya está mas legible, si necesitáis algo más lo puedo poner

Comment: Solo dices que te da error, ¿que error te da? un nullpointerexception, un inputmismatchexception... y en que caso te da ese error? porque dices que de primeras no te da el error